# Database Buffer for Nested SQL statement

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

Suppose I have a relation Employee(...) which stores information for employees including id, names, salary, etc. Now I want to find all employees whose salary is greater than the average salary of all employees. So I write the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVERAGE(salary) FROM employee)
```

A question goes over and over in my mind is that: is it true that the nested SELECT comment will be executed will be executed for comparison for each tuple of Employee relation (i.e, if we have 1 million tuples in Employee, then this nested block will be executed 1 million times), or it is just executed some times and then the result will be buffered for further comparison of further tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL language is one where you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*, and it's then up to the particular database system's optimizer to try to find an efficient way to do it.

Most sane database systems will observe that the subquery does not rely on the outer query in any way (it's uncorrelated) and so will only run the subquery once.

---

On the other hand, if your query looked like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e1
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVERAGE(e2.salary) FROM employee e2
                where e2.start_date < e1.start_date)
```

That is, "find all employees whose salaries are greater than the average for all employees who started before them" - now we have a correlated subquery. The optimizer may still be able to develop some cunning strategy to avoid doing too much work<sup>1</sup>, but now your milage may vary - it will very much depend on your specific database product.

<sup>1</sup>We can scan through the table once in ascending `start_date` order and maintain two variables, a count of the number of rows seen and the sum of salaries. On any particular row, we can use those variables to compute the average so far and then compare that with the salary of the current row to decide whether it should be emitted. Then add the salary to the sum and add 1 to the count and move on to the next row. Whether any database product actually performs such an optimization, I do not know.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just curious about this thing as my teacher explained that within this query, the nested has to be executed every time for each tuple. Maybe, he had a small mistake here. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @DucCuong - in *general*, if you're not discussing a particular database product, I'd say the teacher is incorrect - if the query is as you have it in your question, and not like the example I've added to my answer.